# Ubuntu Server 17.04 - udev rule(s) for Blu-Ray Drive

Tags: mount, 17.04, udev, blu-ray

I'm trying to create a `udev` rule that will allow non-root users to mount a disk inserted into the Blu-Ray drive on an arbitrary mount point.

Since the drive is permanent, but the disks aren't, I'm not using `/etc/fstab` - my understanding, which could be wrong, is that `/etc/fstab` isn't appropriate for this situation.

I've created a file called `10-bluray.rules` in my non-root home and symlinked it to `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-bluray.rules`.  The rule that I have defined is:

```
ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sr[0-9]*", ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_STATE}=="complete", GROUP="users"
```

Yet after running `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`, and ejecting and inserting a disk, my `/dev` still looks like this:

```
brw-rw---- 1 root cdrom    11,   0 2017-09-09 00:52 sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           3 2017-09-09 00:52 dvdrw -> sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           3 2017-09-09 00:52 dvd -> sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           3 2017-09-09 00:52 cdrw -> sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           3 2017-09-09 00:52 cdrom -> sr0
```

With the group set to `cdrom` instead of `users` as specified in the `udev` rule.

I've even checked with `sudo udevadm test /dev/sr0` and it doesn't indicate any problems with the rules:

```
=== trie on-disk ===
tool version:          232
file size:         8775171 bytes
header size             80 bytes
strings            1849483 bytes
nodes              6925608 bytes
Load module index
Found container virtualization none
timestamp of '/etc/systemd/network' changed
timestamp of '/lib/systemd/network' changed
Parsed configuration file /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
Created link configuration context.
timestamp of '/etc/udev/rules.d' changed
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/10-bluray.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-vm-hotadd.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-apport.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-firmware.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/55-dm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/56-lvm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-block.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-bridge-network-interface.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-crda.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-drm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-evdev.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-open-vm-tools.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-alsa.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-dm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-qemu-system-common.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-serial.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-tvbutler-perms.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-vlan-network-interface.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/61-persistent-storage-android.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/63-md-raid-arrays.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-btrfs-dm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-btrfs.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-md-raid-assembly.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/66-snapd-autoimport.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-bcache.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-lvm-metad.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-android-tools-adb.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-android-tools-fastboot.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-debian-uaccess.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-iscsi-network-interface.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-mouse.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-power-switch.rules
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/70-snap.core.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-touchpad.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/71-power-switch-proliant.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/71-u-d-c-gpu-detection.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-special-net-names.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-usb-net-by-mac.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-probe_mtd.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/78-graphics-card.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/78-sound-card.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-debian-compat.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-docker.io.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-ifupdown.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-snappy-assign.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks2.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hdparm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-keyboard-configuration.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-regulatory.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-alsa-restore.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-console-setup.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-cd-devices.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/99-vmware-scsi-udev.rules
rules contain 393216 bytes tokens (32768 * 12 bytes), 31005 bytes strings
21448 strings (173557 bytes), 18376 de-duplicated (145625 bytes), 3073 trie nodes used
unable to open device '/sys/dev/sr0'
Unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context.
```

My understanding of the `udev` rule processing is that rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` override any rules defined in `/lib/udev/rules.d/` (which is where the majority of them are, apparently) - is that not correct?

Ultimately my goal is to allow a user to issue `mount /dev/sr0 /<blah>/<blah>` without the use of `sudo` - is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

- AFAIK, the correct way to give regular users access to CDROM is by adding them to `cdrom` group.

  1. Add existing users to `cdrom` group
  2. Add `cdrom` group to default groups of `useradd` in `/etc/default/useradd` file. Reference: [Reasons behind the default groups and users on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156473/12209)
- If you still want to try `udev` approach.

  Yes the rules in `/etc` override the ones in `/lib` but only those matching same filename in both folders. So all other files with unique name are not omitted.

  1. To me, using very low order `10-` is not good for user custom rules. Any rule with `>10-` (alphanumeric order) which set the `GROUP` too for same node will override your custom rule. So try changing it to `99-` or `90-`'s at least.
  2. For `ACTION=="change"`, check if this event is triggered when CD drive is added if it has hot-plug option, using `udevadm monitor`. Otherwise, use `ACTION=="add"` instead.